# How to combine if statement and sort on linux command?

Tags: linux, sorting, conditional-statements, command-prompt

I want to run a Perl script multiple times using the command line for a folder containing .coordinates.txt files, doing multiples "actions," and as the last step, I want to make a sort based on first-line value.
I wrote this:

```
 for i in ./*gb.coordinates.txt; do perl myscript $i | 
        awk 'NR==1 {print $2,"\t***here"; next } 1'|sed '2d'| #the output has an empty line in the second row so I remove it and I add "\t***here" to have and idea about the first line value after my final sorting

        if [[awk 'FNR == 1 && $1>0']] then {sort -k1nr} else {sort -k1n} fi
         > $i.allvalues.txt;
   done
```

Until here:

```
for i in ./*gb.coordinates.txt; do perl myscript $i | awk 'NR==1 {print $2,"\t***here"; next } 1'|sed '2d' > $i.allvalues.txt; done
```

Everything works properly.

So as l wrote above my final step I want to obtain is a sort like this:

```
 if the first line of my output >=0 then sort -k1n else sort -k1nr
```

The output before the `if condition` is :

```
XXXX   eiter positive number or negative \t***here
32
4455
-2333
23
-123
```

And I want my output be like:

if xxxx= positive

```
xxxx (going in the correct order)  \t***here
4455
32
23
-123
-2333
```

if xxxx= negative

```
xxxx (going in the correct order)   \t***here 
-2333
-123
23
32
4455
```

So my problem is that I don't know who to connect if statement along with sort.

Comment: You don't put `{}` around commands in shell `if` statements.

Comment: @Barmar even without {} it doestn work.

Comment: That's not the only problem.

Comment: Your `[[ ]]` syntax is also wrong (it needs spaces around them), and you can't use `awk` as a condition there.

Comment: I was starting to write an answer, but I can't really figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://shellcheck.net/) will help get the syntax right. Do your readers a favor and split this up into multiple lines. It's unreadable all jammed together.

Comment: @Barmar I want to find the first value position's in the final sorting, So I used  "\t***here" as a trick

Comment: @ShellCheck I will edit the first code line, but please judge me with lenience as I am not familiar with programming syntax.

Comment: also not an answer — but rather than combining perl, awk, and sed you can probably do what you're attempting all within a perl script, or possibly all within an awk script.

Comment: @Stephen P I know but unfortunately I am not so familiar with informatics and this is how I realized it. :-(

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `awk`. Pipe the output of the perl script to a shell block that reads the first line, tests whether it's positive or negative, and then calls the appropriate sort.

```
for i in ./*gb.coordinates.txt; do 
    perl myscript $i | {
        read _ firstline __
        if (( firstline > 0 ))
        then sort -k1nr
        else sort -k1n
        fi
    } > $i.allvalues.txt
done
```

Comment: I got an ">" blinking on the output

Comment: I don't get that, but I did need to fix the conditional syntax do to arithmetic comparison instead of string.

Comment: I got a ">" then my cursor is blinking ..... So If I understand this well that means the program is expecting a value.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. That would happen if you entered an unbalanced quote or something like that. I suggest you put this in a script rather than run it interactively.